# Define own header in webpy

Tags: python, web.py

I look after many links to find how can I define my proprietary header in webpy. Can you help me, please. I need to define my own http header like ("X-UploadedFile") and then use it with `web.input()`

Answer (score 1):

Headers aren't part of `web.input()`, they're part of the "environment".

You can add headers, to be sent to your client using `web.header('My-Header', 'header-value')`.

You can read headers sent by your client using: `web.ctx.env.get('MY_HEADER')` (Note all-caps, and use of underline rather than dash).